# Index is there but not working after creating a new partition or dropping partition for the partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle partitioned table and has an index for the `project_code` with the follow sql. We do following two things every day:

1. Create a new partition and insert data into this partition.
2. Drop old partition

After several days, I found the query is slower, when I see the execution plan for

```
select * from MY_TABLE where project_code = '123'
```

The index is still there but the index doesn't work for the above sql

If I drop and recreate the index, the index will work and the query much faster

I am not sure whether creating/dropping partition causes this issue, and how I can fix this problem

```
-- Create table
create table MY_TABLE
(
  country_code  VARCHAR2(50),
  project_code  VARCHAR2(100),
  item_code     VARCHAR2(100),
  BATCHES       NUMBER
)
partition by list (BATCHES)
(
  partition P1499736558 values (1499736558)
    tablespace MY_DATA
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    ),
  partition P1499760276 values (1499760276)
    tablespace MY_DATA
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    ),
  partition P1499846713 values (1499846713)
    tablespace MY_DATA
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    ),
  partition P1499933071 values (1499933071)
    tablespace MY_DATA
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    )
);
-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create index IDX_PROJECT_CODE on MY_TABLE (PROJECT_CODE)
  tablespace MY_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 160K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

Comment: Most probably the Index becomes stale and that's why the CBO  (Cost Based Optimizer )doesn't use it. Further more, the data in the new partition is brand new and you need to collect statistics on it, so that it can be taken into account by the CBO also. Read more on Index staleness and table column staleness and how those relate to the CBO decisions.

Comment: You said it - after re-creating the Index - it's ok. If I were to administer this process, I would always do the following, after completing the whole process: Gather table (column) statistics, gather index statistics, gather partition statistics. Check this link: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/efficient-statistics-maintenance-for-partitioned-tables-using-incremental-statistics-part-1